# CSS alternative to the CSS plus sign selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to figure out if there is a CSS alternative to using the CSS plus sign selector so that my css slider can be used in older browsers that do not support the plus sign selector. I'm looking for a CSS alternative. But is there is a way to detect browsers that do not support the CSS plus sign selector and use a Jquery alternative I would like to know how to go about this to thanks.

Here is a link to my Jsfiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/2hmb60w0/

HTML

```
<form class="sliders">
    <input type="radio" name="slider-choice" id="first-slider" checked />
    <div class="slider-container">
        <div class="slider">
            <p>Some Random Text...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="second-slider" class="prev"></label>
            <label for="second-slider" class="next"></label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="radio" name="slider-choice" id="second-slider" />
    <div class="slider-container">
        <div class="slider">
            <p>Even Some More Random Text...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="first-slider" class="prev"></label>
            <label for="first-slider" class="next"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS

```
.sliders {
    width: 600px;
    position: relative;
}

.sliders input{ 
    display: none; 
}

.slider {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 600px;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
}

.nav label {
  margin-top: 65px;
    width: 85px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    color: black;
    font-size: 6em;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, .6);
}

.slider:hover + .nav label, .slider:focus + .nav label{ 
    opacity: 0.6; 
}

.nav label:hover, .nav label:focus{ 
    opacity: 1; 
}

.nav .next{ 
    right: 0;
}

.prev:before{
    content: '\2770';
}

.next:before{
    content: '\2771';
}

input:checked + .slider-container .slider{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}

input:checked + .slider-container .nav label{ 
    display: block; 
}

p{
    padding: 100px 20px;
    width: 560px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #dae1ef;
}
```

Comment: Older than IE7, really?

Comment: @Roope I'm just curious because some people prefer older browsers, beats me why.

Comment: @linkNES In about two weeks, Microsoft will no longer support ie10 and below https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support

Comment: @Adam Buchanan Smith thanks for the info but is IE11 the same as EDGE or is EDGE a whole different browser?

Comment: And its not because they like older browsers, its because they cannot afford a newer computer lol\

Comment: Well, some people prefer black'n'white screens, but it doesn't mean we should optimize all images for grayscale, right? EDGE comes after IE11, think of it as IE12.

Comment: You have a bigger issue here than you realize.  The CSS `transform` and `transition` properties will also break in older browsers, so the adjacent sibling selector (+ sign) will be the least of your worries.  Your best bet is to have the slider degrade gracefully into something reasonable, which is up to you to decide.  Remember, a website does not have to look exactly the same in all browsers.

Comment: @Marc Audet There is browser specific css for both those properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to support IE8- (which doesn't support `+` selector) I'd recommend you to use [polyfill](https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/).